# how to focus on navbar-list-items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is an issue with the custom filter and custom directive I made. the custom directive is for focussing the navbar and custom filter is for highlighting the search results. Until the filter is not attached, the directive works fine. But as soon as I implement my filter, directive stops working. 
here is the code

.js

```
app.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
return function(text, phrase) {
    if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
        '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
 }
})

app.directive('focus', function() {
 return {
    restrict: 'A',

    link: function($scope,element,attributes) {

        element.bind('keydown', function(e) {
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if (code === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                element.next().focus();
            }
        });
    }
 }
})
```

html

```
 <li>
                                <ul ng-repeat = "info in infos | filter:curInfo.name"  >
                                    <img src="{{info.image.link}}"/> {{info.name}}
                                    <li ng-repeat="group in info.groups | filter: curInfo" ng-bind-html="group.name | highlight:curInfo.name">
                                        <a href="#">{{group.name}}</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <div class="add list">
                                    <a href="" ng-click="addGroup(groups)">+Add group </a>
                                    </div>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
```

Comment: Could you post demo with above mentioned behavior?

Comment: Also where is `custom filter` code?

Comment: @MaximShoustin hi, the custom filter is the one which I named highlight(located on the top of .js code) and sorry I don't know how to attach a screenshot.